# Difference between Front Tracking and Front Capturing Method

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I am having difficulty understanding the difference between interface capturing and interface tracking schemes. It is important to track it for solving Navier Stokes equation and other fluid problems in two-phase (multi-phase) flow. I have read a few papers ([here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Esjsuresh/mirjalili2017.pdf))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, interface capturing method firstly defines a color function within on each mesh cell, that is:
$$H(x) = \begin{cases}1 &, when\; in \; fluid\;1 \newline 0 &, when\; in\;fluid\;2      \end{cases}$$
and then the interface can be calculated through calculation of this color function.(For example, when VOF is applied, you need to figure out the interface zones with condition of $0 < \phi < 1 $, where $\phi$ is the VOF function.)
While with interface tracking method, the interface is a curve(2D) or a curved surface(3D) represented by connected marker point, thus the interface is explicitly given. The image below is a sketch for interface tracking method.

[image]

A useful textbook is highly recommended.

> Tryggvason, Grétar, Ruben Scardovelli, and Stéphane Zaleski. Direct numerical simulations of gas–liquid multiphase flows. Cambridge university press, 2011.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I understood as well.